# limit of $\frac {x_{n+1}}{1+x_n}=0$, find limit of $x_n$

Tags: limits

Let $(x_n)_{n\ge1}$ be a sequence with the property that $x_n+1\neq 0$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac {x_{n+1}}{1+x_n}=0$. Prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} {x_{n}}=0$

Comment: yes for the first question, as for the second I don't know how to prove it, I tried with the $\epsilon$ definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n\let\epsilon\varepsilon$ large enough we have $\left|\frac{x_{n+1}}{1+x_n}\right|<\epsilon<1$, hence $|x_{n+1}|<\epsilon|1+x_n|\le \epsilon+\epsilon |x_n|$. Thus if we let $a_n=|x_n|-\frac\epsilon{\epsilon+1}$ we see that (for $n\gg 0$) we have $a_{n+1}<\epsilon a_n$. In particular, $a_n$ is bounded and $\limsup a_n\le 0$, hence $0\le \limsup|x_n|\le\frac\epsilon{\epsilon+1}$. As the latter gets arbitrarily small, $x_n\to 0$ follows.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If you know that $\frac{x_{n+1}}{1+x_n}\to 0$, then eventually $\left\vert\frac{x_{n+1}}{1+x_n}\right\vert\le\varepsilon$. Use this to bound the growth of $x_n$, and then take $\varepsilon$ to be arbitrarily small.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say: $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty } x_n = c \neq 0 $, then it follows: $$ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n+1} = \frac{c}{c+1} \neq 0 \text{ for } c \neq -1 $$

$\Rightarrow $, if $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty } x_n $ exists then: $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty } x_n = 0 $